# Ask runtime permissions on Target SDK Version 22

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I have an application whose target sdk version is 22, and I want to show the users **REQUESTING PERMISSION DIALOG**(**if the user has turned off the permission from settings**, or is there any code to turn off the permission from the settings with a code ?) When I use requestPermission code (on target sdk version 22):

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        1);
```

It gives me grantResults in **onRequestPermissionsResult** length ==0. WHY ? Can't I show dialog on targetSdkVersion=22 ?

I don't want to change the target sdk version of my app(due to some reasons), but want to show popup myself to user(for some of the dangerous permissions).

Comment: Runtime Permission Starting with Android 6.0 (API level 23).It is not Required in Version 22

Comment: because the permissions are requested on Runtime from API 23 and above

Comment: "I don't want to change the target sdk version of my app(due to some reasons)" -- bear in mind that [you will not be able to update your app on the Play Store, starting later in 2018, if you do not raise your `targetSdkVersion` to a more-current level](https://commonsware.com/blog/2018/01/08/android-version-ratchet.html). Other app distribution channels may follow suit.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I will update it soon @CommonsWare.